# Proof Verification: If $y\neq 0$ and $|y-y_0|<\min(\frac{|y_0|}{2},\frac{ε|y_0|^2}{2})$ then $y_0\neq 0$ and $|\frac {1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}|<ε$

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-verification, inequality

This is problem 22 from Spivak's Calculus 4th ed., Chapter 1:

> If $y\neq 0$ and $|y-y_0|<\min\left(\frac{|y_0|}{2},\frac{\varepsilon|y_0|^2}{2}\right)$ then $y_0\neq 0$ and $\left|\frac {1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|<\varepsilon$.

This is my proof:

$$|y_0|-|y|\leq|y-y_0|<\frac{|y_0|}{2} \Rightarrow \frac{|y_0|}{2}<|y|\Rightarrow\frac{\varepsilon|y_0|^2}{2}<\varepsilon|y_0||y|$$

Therefore, $$|y-y_0|<\varepsilon|y_0||y|=\varepsilon|y_0\cdot y|$$

$$|y-y_0| \cdot\left|\frac{1}{y_0 \cdot y}\right| < \varepsilon \Rightarrow \left|\frac{1}{y_0}-\frac{1}{y}\right|=\left|\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y_0}\right|<\varepsilon\,,$$ which completes the proof.

My proof is slightly different to the one Spivak offers, so I'm posting it to get it verified. Is it correct?

Comment: You need to show that $y_0 \neq 0$. Otherwise, your proof breaks down wherever you decided to divide by $|y_0|$. However, showing $y_0 \neq 0$ is not that hard. Can you see?

Comment: Would it be correct to prove it in the following way? "Assume that $y_0=0$. Then $\frac {|y_0}{2} = 0 \Rightarrow |y-y_0|=|y|<0$. However, since $|y|\geq 0$ for all $y$, a contradiction is reached, proving that $y_0\neq 0$"

Comment: Yes, that is how you show $y_0 \neq 0$. Spivak cleverly disallowed that possibility by abusing the absolute value operation.